# Integrating function of two variables

Tags: integration

I have been given this question for homework and I cannot get the same answer as I get on wolfram alpha, can someone run me through how they would calculate this question?

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx$$

In my attempts I split the equation into

$$ \int x\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx$$

then integrated by parts but from here I am lost.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$$\frac12\int \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx.$$ Now substitute $u=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Alright I will try this, but to help myself further, why did you do that? If this makes it easier to solve how did you know before solving it?

Comment: Well, as you can see, after the substitution you will get $(1/2)\int \frac1{\sqrt u} du$, which is easier to evaluate. For your second question, I would say practice.

Comment: Okay just out of curiosity in the end I got simply $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but both the online integral calculators I put this equation into I got functions on logs, am I still incorrect?

Comment: Is $y $ related to  $x $?

Comment: I really am not sure if it is or not haha, this integral is part of a larger PDE that I was given to solve. The whole problem is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + 3y\cos(3xy) + 3x^2y^2$, I broke this down into three separate integrals the first one being the question I posted

Comment: @Asyu7 Haha, that's interesting. I'm not familiar with PDE's, so I'm helpless. I would recommend posting a new question including the necessary details. (Sorry for the late response. )